# FMX Multi point gradients

Tags: delphi, gradient, firemonkey

I am trying to apply a multi point gradient to a TRectangle.
If I just set a two point gradient everything works well, but using the same TRectangle and trying to apply 5 points I am only seeing a partial gradient.

If I use the Delphi IDE to set the multi point gradient it works just fine (in the form preview), the problem is how do I do it in code, I couldn't find any sample code in my searches.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
BlockBG                                 := TRectangle.Create(MainForm);
BlockBG.Parent                          := MainForm;
BlockBG.Fill.Kind                       := TBrushKind.Gradient;
BlockBG.SetBounds(0,0,clientWidth,clientHeight);

While BlockBG.Fill.Gradient.Points.Count < 5 do BlockBG.Fill.Gradient.Points.Add;

BlockBG.Fill.Gradient.Points[0].Color := $FF535b5e;
BlockBG.Fill.Gradient.Points[1].Color := $FFfefefe;
BlockBG.Fill.Gradient.Points[2].Color := $FF4a5154;
BlockBG.Fill.Gradient.Points[3].Color := $FFfdfdfd;
BlockBG.Fill.Gradient.Points[4].Color := $FF535b5e;
BlockBG.Fill.Gradient.Points[0].Offset := 0.0;
BlockBG.Fill.Gradient.Points[1].Offset := 0.25;
BlockBG.Fill.Gradient.Points[2].Offset := 0.5;
BlockBG.Fill.Gradient.Points[3].Offset := 0.75;
BlockBG.Fill.Gradient.Points[4].Offset := 1;

BlockBG.Repaint;
```

Comment: What do you mean with *`a partial gradient`*?

Comment: @TomBrunberg not all the points in the gradient are drawn, but like I wrote in the answer, this seems to be a Delphi GPU canvas bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the GPU Canvas implementation in Delphi 10.3, if I comment out "FMX.Types.GlobalUseGPUCanvas := True;" it works as intended.

Comment: Comment it out from where?

Comment: In windows application, the canvas is not set to GPU by default, in my app, I was testing the gradient code with a GPU canvas by setting GlobalUseGPUCanvas to True.  As soon as the GPU canvas is disabled, the gradient is rendered correctly, so I'm assuming the issue is a bug in the GPU canvas implementation of multi point gradients.